# Exchanging the axes in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have been wondering about this for a while, and it might already be implemented in `gnuplot` but I haven't been able to find info online.

When you have a data file, it is possible to exchange the axes and assign the "dummy variable", say x, (in gnuplot's help terminology) to the vertical axis:

```
plot "data" u 1:2 # x goes to horizontal axis, standard
plot "data" u 2:1 # x goes to vertical axis, exchanged axes
```

However, when you have a function, you need to resort to a parametric function to do this. Imagine you want to plot x = y² (as opposite to y = x²), then (as far as I know) you need to do:

```
set parametric
plot t**2,t
```

[image]

which works nicely in this case. I think however that a more flexible approach would be desirable, something like

```
plot x**2 axes y1x1 # this doesn't work!
```

Is something like the above implemented, or is there an easy way to use y as dummy variable without the need to `set parametric`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here is another ugly, but gnuplot-only variant: Use the special filename `'+'` to generate a dynamic data set for plotting:

```
plot '+' using ($1**2):1
```

The development version contains a new feature, which allows you to use dummy variables instead of column numbers for plotting with `'+'`:

```
plot sample [y=-10:10] '+' using (y**2):(y)
```

I guess that's what come closest to your request.

Comment: This improves in ugliness but still ugly. I still would like to see an `axes y1x1` (or equivalent) option implemented.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen, parametric plots are pretty common in order to achieve your needs. 
If you really hate parametric plots and you have no fear for a VERY ugly solutions, I can give you my method...

My trick is to use a data file filled with a sequence of numbers. To fit your example, let's make a file `sq` with a sequence of reals from `-10` to `10` :

```
seq -10 .5 10 > sq
```

And then you can do the magic you want using gnuplot :

```
plot 'sq' u ($1**2):($1)
```

And if you uses linux you can also put the command directly in the command line :

```
plot '< seq -10 .5 10' u ($1**2):($1)
```

I want to add that I'm not proud of this solution and I'd love the "axis y1x1" functionality too.

Comment: Yes, I've used ugly stuff like this in the past to generate contours for color-map plots. For functions I'd say I still prefer parametric plots. It's no big deal, just striking to me that something as simple as `axes y1x1` and potentially so handy is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to simply invert or exchange the axes in gnuplot when plotting a function.

The reason comes from the way functions are plotted in the normal plotting mode.  There is a set of points at even intervals along the x axis which are sampled (frequency set by `set samples`) and the function value computed.  This only allows for well-behaved functions; one y-value per x-value.

Comment: Yes thanks, I already pointed this out in the first part of my question. This is why it seems odd to me that the option is not easily available for functions as well.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that part of your question!  See my edits to my answer for an explanation.

Comment: My view is in the end it's not really a matter of whether the function is well behaved or not, but just about being flexible with how the representation is carried out. y = f(x) = x² is just as well-behaved as x = f(y) = y², there is a simple axis rotation involved. It's no big deal but just kind of bothers me that this is not implemented, which is probably my fault anyway...